# R- How to match data based on a date interval to a specific date in a separate dataframe?

Tags: r, date, match, intervals

I have two dataframes, one has GPS points which are all tagged with a specific date. The other has drought measurements (in the form of PDSI values) taken every 5 days, and an interval column spanning those 5 days (i.e. 2010-01-01 UTC--2010-01-05 UTC). What I want to do is add a new column to the GPS dataframe with the PDSI value on the date the GPS point was taken (with all dates that fall in an interval getting the same PDSI value). I tried to write a function that cycles through the PDSI dataframe to find the time interval the date falls in and then report the PDSI value for that interval. Then I used `sapply()` to run that function over the GPS dataframe date column. It worked for the first 3 rows of my GPS dataframe (all in the same time interval) but then only gave `NULL` for the rest of the rows. I think the issue is in my function because when I give it just a date (that I know falls in a time interval) it still gives me `NULL`.  Here is my code:

```
interval_fun <- function(date, pdsi){
  data <- for(i in 1:length(pdsi)) {
    if(date %within% pdsi$Interval[i]) {return(pdsi$pdsi[i])}
  }
return(data)
}

test <- GPS %>%
     mutate(PDSI = sapply(X = GPS$FullDate, interval_fun, pdsi))

# Test the function with just simple dates, it works for the first 4 intervals, but not beyond
head(pdsi)
  Start_Date   End_Date                       Interval   pdsi
1 2010-01-01 2010-01-05 2010-01-01 UTC--2010-01-05 UTC -1.117
2 2010-01-06 2010-01-10 2010-01-06 UTC--2010-01-10 UTC -1.076
3 2010-01-11 2010-01-15 2010-01-11 UTC--2010-01-15 UTC -1.129
4 2010-01-16 2010-01-20 2010-01-16 UTC--2010-01-20 UTC -1.142
5 2010-01-21 2010-01-25 2010-01-21 UTC--2010-01-25 UTC -1.176
6 2010-01-26 2010-01-30 2010-01-26 UTC--2010-01-30 UTC -1.214

interval_fun(ymd("2010-01-2"), pdsi)
[1] -1.117

interval_fun(ymd("2010-01-8"), pdsi)
[1] -1.076

interval_fun(ymd("2010-01-11"), pdsi)
[1] -1.129

interval_fun(ymd("2010-01-20"), pdsi)
[1] -1.142

interval_fun(ymd("2010-01-21"), pdsi)
NULL
```

I've got no idea what's happening here, any insight or alternative ideas would be welcome! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If i'm not wrong, you are searching for the pdsi value in a selected day right?

Supose a new variable, called " day ", which is the day you are interested in. Let's say your data frame is called " df ". In this case, use

```
day <- as.Date("2010-01-04")
subset(df$pdsi,((day>=df$Start_date) & (day<=df$End_date)))
```

I strongly recommend you to avoid for loops to check what's the value of the cell in each cell. Since this is a very poor performance, R has several better functions to " filter " data frames.

Comment: Thank you, that helped! I rewrote the function to:
`interval_fun <- function(date, pdsi) {
  data <- subset(pdsi$pdsi, date %within% pdsi$Interval)
  return(data)
}`
And it worked!